# usage: "Neither or either" plus "singular or plural noun"

Tags: adjectives

> In Western blot analysis, expression of either proteins resulted in the down-regulation.

In the above sentence, should I use *either proteins* or *either protein*? Can I replace it with *neither protein*?

Comment: To be able to answer your question, we would need to know what exactly you would like to say. Do you mean that down-regulation occurs if: (a) one or the other (or both?) protein is expressed (2 possible proteins); (b) any number of multiple (more than 2) proteins are expressed; or (c) both proteins (out of 2 proteins) are _not_ expressed; or (d) no proteins (out of multiple proteins) are expressed?

Answer (score 1):

*Either Xs* means:

- There are 2 Xs.
- Only one X can be involved at a time in what follows.
- Whichever X is chosen of the two, what follows applies to that X.

*Neither Xs*  means:

- There are 2 Xs.
- Only one X can be involved at a time in what follows.
- Whichever X is chosen of the two, what follows does not apply to that X.

The words mean different things, *neither* being a "negative form" of *either*.  Depends on what you want to say.